# Categorize observations in dataframe by different identifiers

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling, rtweet

I've searched around for a solution to this problem, but can't seem to find any.

I have pulled tweets from Danish MP's using the rtweet package to acces the Twitter API. I used get_gimeline() to pull the data.

```
get_timeline(c(politikere), n = 100,  parse = TRUE, since_id = "1315756184247435264", max_id = "1333904927559725056", type = "recent") %>%
  dplyr::filter(created_at > "2020-10-25" & created_at <="2020-12-01")
```

Now i would like to categorize the different Twitter users by their Party ID, in order to do some pary specific sentiment analysis.
From the API call you get all sorts of information in to a tibble dataframe e.g "user id" spanning to around 90 different variables.

| user_id | status_id | created_at | screen_name | text | description | ...x_i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The point is that I want to create a new column in the dataset named party_id and I want to assign a new value onto each user according to the party they belong to:
I would want to create a column which identifies the party affilitation. It should look something like this:

| user_id | status_id | created_at | screen_name | text | description | **party_id** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234346 | 683901040 | 2020-11-23 | larsen_mc | gg.. | Danish MP.. | **Conservatives** |

I looked at the dplyr package but I can't quite get my head around how to assign the same value to different rows that does not share the same identifiers. If e.g all the conservative MP's shared the same status_id it would be a somewhat easier task by using inner_join, but every user has it's own unique identifier in this case (of course).

Here is the example_data

```
structure(list(user_id = c("2373406198", "4360080437", "3512158337", 
"746909257", "36910691", "58550919", "279986859", "1225930531", 
"26263965", "2222188479"), status_id = c("1354094283230474241", 
"1354707826317393922", "1354391556900483072", "1347169543853117444", 
"1354866447735005185", "1332633849659088897", "1355522537669734401", 
"1355554489361686530", "1329028442105458688", "1330791375449829376"
), created_at = structure(c(1611676209, 1611822489, 1611747085, 
1610025223, 1611860307, 1606559643, 1612016732, 1612024349, 1605700047, 
1606120363), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    screen_name = c("jacobmark_sf", "RuneLundEL", "kimvalentinDK", 
    "TommyPetersenDK", "JuulMona", "Blixt22", "JanEJoergensen", 
    "RasmusJarlov", "StemLAURITZEN", "olebirkolesen")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Hopes this makes sense

Best,
Gustav

Comment: Please provide some sample data using `dput` and provide your expected output for that data

Comment: I've uploaded some example data in the bottom of the question outlined above. What I want is to create another column with names of the Danish Parties (Parti_id), and then assign this Parti identifier to each observation in my dataset based on what party the twitter user belongs to.

Comment: Is there any lookup table for identifying which party each user belong to?

Comment: you can create a master list of the `screen_name` and map that to the `party_type` parameter. Then join this master data with your dataset for further use.
 
The trouble here is that their affiliation to a specific party is not relevant to creating an account on Twitter, even if the views they express using the account are. For e.g., if I am not familiar with Danish MPs and won't know their party affiliation by looking at their user profile.

Comment: No, sadly there is no lookup table. That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Aramis7d what would that look like? Could you give an coding example?

Comment: you can create something like below for the lookup table. 
this is more a manual exercise than something that can be done by code.

| screenname | partytype |
| -------- | ------- |
| jacob    | A       |
| rune   | B         |
| kim   | A          |

Comment: Okay, so now i have assigned the partytype to the MP's manually. How do i then match the column of party_type from my dataframe (df1) with all the MP's to the dataframe with all the tweets in them (df2)? I have over 7000 tweets that follow the same logic as the dataframe above e.g i could use df$screen_name to map the party_type parameter. How do I match df1$screen_name with df2$screen_name to assign df1$party_type to all the repeated observations, that is tweets in df2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - I found a solution! After making the identifier manually (called Parti_id) I used the tidyverse package and used left_join():

```
poldata <- poldata %>%   
 select(screen_name,Parti_id)  
FTtweets <- left_join(tmlpol, poldata, by = "screen_name")
```